# What is the easiest/non-technical friendly way to upload and sort through a large dataset (400GB+)?

Tags: sql, database, database-design, amazon-web-services, bigdata

Would like to sort the (largely text) data by date tags first (separating the data by quarters, lets say, even if into different files).  Then would like to perform standard functions like conditional sums on the data.  Without a substantial programming/database background but with a willingness to spend a few days to learn, what's my best bet for a solution?

Comment: What format is your data in? Plain text? XML?

Comment: Use Hadoop and any database say Hbase etc... to sort the file.

Comment: Format is plain text.  Are there any easy to use/non-technical software packages I can use to help sort through it once I get it in the cloud?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to be able to do some queries on your data. I would look into a SQL database solution. The most difficult part would be getting your data into the database.

All of AWS's relational databases can import from text files:
Microsoft's SQL Server: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178129.aspx
Oracle: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/text.111/b28304/aload.htm
MySQL: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysqlimport.html

I would base the decision purely on whichever one is easier to load your file. If you are budget constrained, you can download MySQL and not do this whole cloud thing. Just keep it on your local computer, assuming you have enough disk space to host the database.

After that's done, they all support SQL, which makes it very easy for you to query your data. If you don't want to write your own SQL, there are tools for you to create queries by drag and drop. But being a programmer, I highly recommend writing your own queries, or coming back here for some query help.

Comment: Thank you jtseng.  Out of curiosity, what programs would you recommend to create queries by drag and drop (GUI) on an SQL database?

Is there a way to have a GUI/drag and drop interface while all of my data has been uploaded in the cloud (ie dragging/dropping via the cloud from my computer, so computations are faster than whatever I have in memory on my own computer)?

Thank you

Comment: @user2535088 I actually have never used one, so I can't make a good suggestion. Here's a list I found on Google: http://sourceforge.net/projects/sqleo/, http://www.quackit.com/sql_server/sql_server_2008/tutorial/query_designer.cfm, http://www.devart.com/dbforge/sql/querybuilder/ Good luck. Maybe you can get a friend to write a couple of queries, or find similiar queries on here.